# better way to write if else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

First time writing Javascript. I just would like know if there is a shorter way of writing this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var letter = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var text;

    if (letter === "5544") {
        text = "Abar, Marlon 1,800";

    } else if (letter === "5545") {
        text = "Pia, Darla 1,800";  

    } else if (letter === "5546") {
        text = "Salazar, Alex 1,500";   

//etc...

    } else {
        text = "Incorrect Account Number";
    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Tried map but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify multiple if statements javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935655/how-to-simplify-multiple-if-statements-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a shorter way to write an `if` statement in that way (which I will assume is what you're asking).  However, there could be a few different ways to write this depending on how many things you want to check.

## **Use a Switch statement**

There is a cleaner way when dealing with multiple cases that `letter` could be.

This would be a `switch` statement and it would look like this:

```
var text;

switch (letter) {
    case "5544":
        text = "Abar, Marlon 1,800";
    break;
    case "5545":
        text = "Pia, Darla 1,800"; 
    break;

    // more cases

    default:
        text = "Incorrect Account Number";
    break;
}
```

This reads a little better than an `if else` statement in some cases.  The `default` keyword here acts as your `else` clause in an `if else` statement.  The `case` acts as your different `if` statements if you will.

Essentially, the `switch` statement above will fall through each of the cases it defines until it finds a case that matches `letter` (such as `"5544"`).  If none matches, it hits the `default` case.  The `break` keyword at the end of each `case` stops things from falling through to the next defined `case` once a match is found.

This method could get cumbersome with more than 6 or 7 cases.

## **Create an object and look up the value**

Now, *a shorter way to get the value you want* could be to define an object and get the value based on what has been entered like so:

```
var letter = document.getElementById('selector').value;
var obj = {
    '5544': 'Abar, Marlon 1,800'
};

if (letter in obj) {
   // do something if found
}
else {
   // do something if not found
}
```

This could be an easy way to get a value if you have many values to check.

## **Other thoughts**

As a side note to all of this, there are short hand `if` statements called ternary statements which you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator ... However, I would not recommend nesting these as it becomes very complicated and not very readable.

## **Conclusion**

So, to reiterate the answer to your question: *No, there isn't really a shorter way to write an `if else` statement with many values.  You can use a `switch` statement to make it cleaner.  Use the object lookup method if you have many values you would like to check.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This gives me a few options to try now. I'm trying to check about 100 items so 100+ if statements looked a lot like bad coding for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dennis:  Sure thing!  Glad to be of service.  I edited my object look up approach to be a little different.  The previous approach assumed the value would always be truthy.  This way, it just checks to see if the key is present.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has object (map) literals.  Use them for terse code.  In your final application you'll get the data for the map from someplace else and not code it directly into your website, but if you did, it would look like this:

```
document.getElementById( "demo" ).innerHTML = {
    "5544" : "Abar, Marlon 1,800",
    "5445" : "Pia, Darla 1,800",
    ...
}[ document.getElementById( "myInput" ).value ];
```

Comment: Thanks. It's just a "basic" website so I think I'll just code it directly. I'll try this again using your example and see if I can get it to work. The first time I tried it it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

you can use switch for a long if - else -if ladder:

```
switch(expression) {
case n:
    code block
    break;
case n:
    code block
    break;
default:
    default code block
}
```

This is how it works:
1)The switch expression is evaluated once.
2)The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case.
3)If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed.

if you need basic tutorials in java script then you should try w3 schools.

Comment: Thanks for the help. w3 schools was the first website I used to help me learn javascript. I actually dont have any programming experience (except waaaay back in high school) so it is a bit confusing for me.