# How to simplify multiple if statements javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have multiple conditions to check. I have to add icons based on the conditions, Then I need to change the background color based on some other set of conditions. I am using if statement. This is my code.

JSON:

```
{
  "date": "2017-05-12",  
  "a": false,
  "b": true,
  "c": true,  
  "d": false,
  "status": "active"
}
```

Javascript:

```
 if (date != -1) {
  //do something
  if (a) {
    //Add icon a
  }
  if (b) {
    //Add icon b
  }
  if (c) {
    //Add icon c
  }
  if (d) {
    //Add icon d
  }
}

if(status == "active"){
  //Background Green
}
else if (status == "onhold"){
  //Background Yellow
}
else if (status == "inactive"){
  //Background Red
}
else{
  //Backgeound Grey
}
```

How do I simplify it?

Comment: You can use a Switch statement instead of if - else.

Comment: also see AND OR and other logical operators. They are also also helpful in combining different if-else conditions into a single condition.

Comment: Conditions such as `if (a == true)` can be simplified as `if (a)`

Comment: And `if (a) someExpression` can be simplified as `a && someExpression`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first half of you code looks fine.
For the second half of your code you should make use of a switch statement. These replace the if-else statements you are using and decide what to do when certain "cases" occur. For example:

```
switch(status) {
    case 'active':
        //background green
        break;
    case 'onhold':
        //background yellow
        break;
    case 'inactive':
        //background red
        break;
    default:
        //background grey
        break;
}
```

Comment: Reduced my if-else code by 2/3. Very nice approach.

Answer (score 7):

My idea is：

```
var icons = {
    a: 'a.png',
    b: 'b.png',
    c: 'c.png',
    d: 'd.png',
}

if (date != -1) {
    Object.keys(icons).forEach(function(key) {
        if (data[key]) {
            //Add icon icons[key]
        }
    });
}

var statusColors = {
    active: 'Green',
    onhold: 'Yellow',
    inactive: 'Grey',
}

//Background statusColors[status]
```

Comment: Faster than a switch?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty good as it is. Is is better to have understandable code than complex code that does exactly the same thing.

You don't have to do

`if (a === true)`

as it's equivalent to

`if ( a )`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "simplify" it, but you can try to use `switch` statement instead:

```
switch (status) {
  case 'active':
    // active
    break;
  case 'onhold':
    // onhold
    break;
  case 'inactive':
    // inactive
    break;
  default:
    console.log('default');
}
```

You can even "group" some conditions:

```
switch (status) {
  case 'active':
  case 'onhold':
    // active AND onhold case
    break;
  case 'inactive':
    // inactive
    break;
  default:
    console.log('default');
}
```

More about `switch` statement -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

For Status variable you can use switch but for the first condition you have to use if-else statements I think.

```
switch (status) {
        case "active":
            //Background Green
            break;
        case "onhold":
            //Background Yellow
            break;
        case "inactive":
            //Background Red
            break;
        default:
            //Backgeound Grey
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't quite give the details of the actions in each case, but if they're very similar, and there's a match between the property name and whatever action you need to take, you can use loops.

```
['a','b','c','d'].forEach(function (k)
{
    if (objectFromJSON[k])
    {
       addIcon(k);
    }
});
```

For the second part, it's slightly more complex as you have status names that don't match the color. You can either:

- define CSS classes with those status names, and use the status name to set the class:

  CSS:

  ```
  .status-active
  {
      background: green;
  }
  .status-onhold
  {
      background: yellow;
  }
  .status-inactive
  {
      background: red;
  }
  ```

  JS:

  ```
  theHTMLobject.classList.addClass('status-'+objectFromJSON.status);
  ```
- use an object's properties (or a Map) to convert the status into a color

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "simplify" or do you mean "shorten" - because the two are almost mutually exclusive (shorter code is often not simpler!)

Your code is clear, and understandable. But it is a bit verbose, and can get much more complex as things grow. Sometimes it *is* better to shorten and the risk of making it a bit harder to understand.

You could consider things like a map between the status and the appropriate color

```
var backgroundStatusMap = {
    "active":"green",
    "onhold": "yellow",
    "inactive": "red"
};

var backgroundColor = backgroundStatusMap[json.status];
```

Things like this can be added to easier if you as add new statuses - without having to trawl for the right place to put a new `if..` condition.

Similarly, you could create a map for the booleans-to-icons

```
var iconMap = {
    "a":"icon_a.png",
    "b": "icon_b.png"
};

function getIcon(json, prop){
    if(json[prop])
      return iconMap[prop];
    return null;
}

var iconA = getIcon(json,"a");
var iconB = getIcon(json,"b");
```

Answer (score -1):

`a?setIconA():b?setIconB:c?setIconC;d?setIconD`

and

`status == "active" ? setGreen() : status == "onhold": setYellow()`

and so on.