# Is there a way to shorten a mostly repetitive if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, repeat

I'm trying to make a number to month conversion. I'm trying to do it with an if statement, e.g. `if(num===0) {month = "January";} else if(num===1) {month = "February";}` etc. Is there a way to shorten this? I imagine it'd be something like `if(num===[0,1,2,3,4,5]) {month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"}`

In other words, is there some kind of way to use an array with an if function, while the if function goes through each one respectively? I am using the p5 library, by the way, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Index with the number into the array, and then verify that the result is not `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not the best at coding, can you give me an example? I don't really understand :)

Comment: `["January", "February", "March", "April"][2] === "March"`. Just use `month = months[num]`.

Comment: You're not the best at coding _yet_.

Comment: you case also use switch case

Comment: If you are new, you might also want to take a look at swtich statements. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp . It is quite common to see for similar problems (but a tiny bit more complex). But yes, the shortest way is like Jeremy Thille is showing you.

Comment: Okay! I didn't actually think of that, but it definitely makes sense. Thanks for all of the help! It says a lot about my skills that I'm getting so many answers right away lol - I'll take a look at the switch case, always looking to learn :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify multiple if statements javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935655/how-to-simplify-multiple-if-statements-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a switch statement

```
var num = 0;
  switch (num) {
    case 0:
      month = "January";
      break;
    case 1:
      month = "February";
      break;
    case 2:
      month = "March";
      break;
    case 3:
      month = "April";
      break;
    case 4:
      month = "May";
      break;
    case 5:
      month = "June";
      break;
    default:
      day = "Unknown Month";
  }
```

Read More: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_switch.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Yeah or just an array and `month = months[num]` ?

Comment: I like the array better, but I need to learn the switch cases too I think.

Comment: Well the array is not only simpler and uses _way_ less code, but it can also be translated easily, if your application has to support internationalization. Good luck with adding multilanguage support with such a `switch` statement

Comment: @JeremyThille your solution is very good, and very concise for this situations; although using a switch statement can help increase functionality.

With the switch statements in place, additional functionality can be added. Think for example changing the background to a Christmas theme during December, or adding a valentine sale banner during February. With using your array the developer will have to add over-complex if statements which is exactly what OP wanted to avoid, cheers and all the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to use a array of months like this:

```
const month = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
];

const answer = month[num];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways than a hardcoded switch.

```js
let locale = 'en-us'

let month = 3 // Apr

let months = [...Array(12).keys()].map(v => new Date(2000, v).toLocaleString(locale, {
  month: 'long'
}))

if (months[month]) {
  console.log('Do something...')
}

// some other examples

let result;

//
result = months[month] || 'Invalid month index'
console.log('by index', result)

//
result = months[month - 1] || 'Invalid month number'
console.log('by month number', result)

//
result = months.findIndex(v => v === new Date().toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long' }))
console.log('find index by name', result)
console.log('use index to get name', months[result])
```

Comment: Whew, this is too complicated for me! I'll keep this filed away, though, and see if I can understand it when I get better at coding...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I think you meant to write `Array(12).keys()` so you would get `0-11` instead of `0-10`.

Answer (score 0):

if ur ranges are mostly contiguous in nature, one way is to pre-make a lookup string that's also simultaneously the keys and the values, like

> `1:JAN:2:FEB:3:MAR: etc`

with a constant-width nature. even 1:J:2:F:3:M:4:A….(i mean it's *feasible* to type in all the names there but then you'll need some padding).

and when then function is called, use a combination of match or substring functions to "cut out" the ones u need first, say  "**`4:APR:5:MAY:6:JUN:7:JUL`**" (you'll have to be creative with ur own notations when u're using single letters each and when 3-5, 4-8 and 1-6-7 duplicate… or just use base-12)

if a 3-letter prefix already satisfy ur needs, then do a high-speed gsub to get rid of all the numbers and delimiters, and change them to a comma or something.

and if u opt for the full months, i dunno how much it'll help at all, but perhaps u can regex sub-in the common suffixes of 9-10-11-12 mostly in one shot, and also 1-2. 5 is already its full name.

another approach is that if ur ranges generally span more than half the year, then even a "subtraction" approach might be preferable to an "addition one" - always start with the full string with all months spelt out. then for the months missing from ur input, blank those out, and return what's leftover.

and say if ur ranges tend to cluster within the same half of the year instead of straddling, then u can even split that index key into 2 to make it faster(the savings are tiny though)

Answer (score -1):

Create an awk definition as follows:

```
getMonth()
{
    awk 'BEGIN{
        months=[January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December] ;
    }{
        print months[$1] ;
    }'
}
```

Then process your input using a call

```
month=`echo ${digit} | getMonth `
```

where digit is assigned a value from 1 to 12.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I have no idea what's going on in this code. I'm sure I'll understand in a year, though... lol

Comment: This is not a JavaScript solution to a specifically JavaScript question.

Comment: My Bad! I did not see the Javacript reference.  My solution fits the bash context, but I am sure there is a similar construct for javascript.

Comment: Thank god, I was right! I saw print and thought that there was some way to combine Python with JS or something