# What is the simplest way to shorten a long if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

**Fully functional (simplified) example below.**

Let's say I have a list of 10 possible abbreviations that could be converted to a full name.
It's not large enough that I'd want to do a lookup in a database.
 What is the simplest if-else solution?

Here's my imaginary solution: Logically, it would makes sense to compare two arrays such as:
`var bar = [foo == sf, foo == ny, foo == la] ? [San Francisco, New York, Los Angeles] : "";`

Otherwise, I have a functioning solution below. Can I do any better than that?

EDIT: The ideal solution would be one line of code. I don't want to use a switch statement as it's not much more efficient to write than an if/else.

```js
bar = "LA";
sf = "SF";
ny = "NY";
la = "LA";
{
if (bar == sf) {
foo = "San Francisco";
} else if (bar == ny) {
foo = "New York";
} else if (bar == la) {
foo = "Los Angeles";
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = foo;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Result</div>
```

Comment: You could use a switch statement.

Comment: I'd use a lookup `lookup = {'f': "foo", 'b': "bar"}; name = lookup[f']'`

Comment: What about a nested ternary ? :)

Comment: @JonasW. with 10 abbreviations, that would get quite messy and unreadable

Comment: @vcapra1 that was a joke.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [better way to write if else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338081/better-way-to-write-if-else-statement)

Comment: @Xufox the answers here are much better, with many great solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify multiple if statements javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935655/how-to-simplify-multiple-if-statements-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `switch`:

```
bar = "LA";
sf = "SF";
ny = "NY";
la = "LA";

switch (bar) {
  case sf:
    foo = "San Fransisco";
    break;
  case ny:
    foo = "New York";
    break;
  case la:
    foo = "Los Angeles";
    break;
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = foo;
```

Alternatively, an if statement could look like this:

```
bar = "LA";
sf = "SF";
ny = "NY";
la = "LA";

if (bar == sf) foo = "San Fransisco";
else if (bar == ny) foo = "New York";
else if (bar == la) foo = "Los Angeles";

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = foo;
```

Leaving out the braces for one-liners shortens the code well.

A nice one-liner for JavaScript could also look like this:

```
bar = "LA";

foo = {
 "LA": "Los Angles",
 "SF": "San Francisco",
 "NY": "New York" 
}[bar];

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = foo;
```

Comment: I really like the solutions you suggest, especially the last one. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You call your last solution a "one-liner" but is there a term to describe that syntax? I want to read more. What exactly is it doing?

Comment: Sorry I meant more of a one-expression-er... lol.  The "one line" I was referring to was the middle section which is all one expression, and could be on all one line but that would make it hard to read.  I'm not sure of any other name for the syntax, other than perhaps a lookup...?

Comment: I understand what you're referring to and it works very well. It really is one line if I don't need to print the result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't using `if` statements but you could achieve this easily using an object:

```js
var cities =  {
 "LA": "Los Angeles",
 "SF": "San Francisco",
 "NY": "New York" 
}

var search = "LA";
var foo = cities[search];

document.body.innerHTML = foo;
```

Comment: This is a great way to avoid an if statement, thanks for sharing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

**IF I were you**, I'l make some changes on my code structure and push all the abbreviation list to any `object` and didn't use any kind of `if/else` or `switch` block. I'll also concatenated the foo value after **Result:** with simple modification on my html

`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += foo;`

```js
var bar = "LA";

var abbr = {
  "SF": "San Francisco",
  "NY": "New York",
  "LA": "Los Angeles",
}

var foo = abbr[bar]; 

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += foo;
```

```html
<div id="test">Result: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use switch case statement, it would be faster. Like this

```
switch (bar) {
   case "SF": foo = "San Fransisco"; break;
   case "NY": foo = "New York"; break;
   case "LA": foo = "Los Angeles"; break;
   default: foo = "";
}
```